# enemy class overlap with each other

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import os 
import random 
from pygame.locals import * # Constants
import math
import sys
import random

pygame.init()  

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,700)) #(length,height)
screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((255,255,255))     # fill the background white 
background = pygame.image.load('stage.png').convert()
Black=(0,0,0)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
x = 20
y = 615
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()   # calls the parent class allowing sprite to initalize
    self.image = pygame.Surface((50,25))   # this is used to create a blank image with the size inputted 
    self.image.fill((0,0,128))    # fills the blank image with colour

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft =(20,615))   # This place the player at the given position   

    self.dist = 10

def update(self): # code to make the character move when the arrow keys are pressed
    if self.rect.right > 100:   # These are to make the player so move constantly
         self.rect.y += 1
         self.rect.x += 2
    if self.rect.bottom == 700:
         pygame.quit() 

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        self.rect.move_ip(-1,0)
    elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0.5,0)
    elif keys[K_UP]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0,-0.5)
    elif keys[K_DOWN]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0,1)
    self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
    #while self.rect == (20,615):
    if keys [K_SPACE]:
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft =(100,100))

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # the enemy class which works fine
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    x = random.randint(50,450)
    self.image = pygame.Surface((50,25))
    self.image.fill((128,0,0))
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft (300, 50))
    self.direction = 0

def update(self):
    self.rect.y += 2 if self.direction == 0 else -2
    if self.rect.bottom >= 600:
        self.direction = 1
    if self.rect.top <= 50:
        self.direction = 0


clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()
enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()  # a group where the enemys will be put
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player) # The group where evry spirte will be put into

for i in range (5):   # creates 5 enemy spirtes
enemy = Enemy()    # calls the enemy class

enemy.rect.x = random.randrange(200, 1100) # makes the enemny spawn random 
enemy.rect.y = random.randrange(50, 600)

enemy_list.add(enemy) # adds the enemy to the group
sprites.add(enemy)
```

I got the code so that the enemies will randomly and then they will move up and down however since the spawning is random they will sometimes overlap i was wondering how i would get it so that they don't overlap when they move up and down
i was wondering if i could do it so they have a gap when they spawns e.g. 50 in x axis but still spawn five enemies

```
def main():  #my main loop 
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    sprites.update()
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    sprites.draw(screen)
    clock.tick(100)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
    pygame.display.flip()   #updates the whole screen



#Collison check
    player_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, enemy_list, True)

    for enemy in player_hit_list:
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
main()
```

Comment: If you are spawning `n` enemies, and you know that they will all spawn with 900 pixels along the x-axis, just assign each enemy a *zone* in which it can spawn of `x / 900` pixels.  In your case, the first enemy will spawn between `x=200 and x=380`, the second between `x=380 and x=560`, third between `x=560 and x=740`, 4th between `x=740 and x=920` and 5th between `x=920 and x=1100`.  You can adjust this zone for each enemy to provide the 50 pixel buffer you require.

Comment: hello i tried using randrange e.g.

Comment: enemy.rect.x = random.randrange(200, 1200, 70) which works but there is still a chance of it overlapping

Comment: Yes, just changing the random number selector won't change the probability of overlaps.  Please see the answer I just posted which tries to explain my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach (I've purposely made the code a little verbose to try to explain what's going on):

```
...

number_of_enemies = 5
min_enemy_x = 200
max_enemy_x = 1100
enemy_x_range = max_enemy_x - min_enemy_x    # zone in which enemies can spawn
enemy_zone_width = enemy_x_range / number_of_enemies  # zone width for each enemy
pixel_buffer = 50  # gap between enemies

for i in range (number_of_enemies):   # creates 5 enemy spirtes
    enemy = Enemy()    # calls the enemy class
    min_x = min_enemy_x + enemy_zone_width * i + pixel_buffer / 2  # minimum x at which current enemy can spawn (including buffer)
    max_x = min_enemy_x + enemy_zone_width * (i + 1) - pixel_buffer / 2  # maximum x at which current enemy can spawn (including buffer)
    enemy.rect.x = random.randrange(min_x, max_x) # makes the enemy spawn random 
    enemy.rect.y = random.randrange(50, 600)

    enemy_list.add(enemy) # adds the enemy to the group
    ...
```

Note that this will produce a 25 pixel buffer at the start and end (so enemies will actually spawn between 225 and 1075), but you can either adjust `min_enemy_x` and `max_enemy_x` to compensate, or remove the buffering for the first and last loop iterations.

Comment: hello thank you for your help i understood the code except for the bit where i is used. please could you explain what it does?

Comment: Sure. `i` is used to create the spawning zones for each enemy. Remember that we've split the spawning area (900 pixels wide) into 5 zones - one for each enemy.  That makes each zone 180 pixels wide (i.e. `enemy_zone_width = 180`.  We use `i` to tell the first enemy (where `i = 0`) that it's minimum x co-ordinate is `enemy_zone_width * i`, and it's maximum x co-ordinate is `enemy_zone_width * (i + 1)`.  That is, for the first enemy, `min_x = 180 * 0` and `max_x = 180 * (0 + 1)`.  So the first enemy spawns between 0 and 180.  Similarly, the second enemy (with `i = 1`) spawns between 180 and 360.

Comment: This continues until the 5th enemy (the one with `i = 4`) spawns between 720 and 900.  These values are all offset by 'min_enemy_x ', so the *actual* pixels values are 200 greater than those I've listed here, but the essence is that `i` creates the spawning zone for each enemy.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to mark the most useful answers as accepted if they have helped you to solve your problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work